# Does Fiddler modify data?

Tags: fiddler, htmlunit

I've been writing a htmlunit program and when I make it use Fiddler as a proxy, I get different results than not using htmlunit with a proxy. This only happens with Fiddler. I tried it with Charles proxy and I got the same results as I would get with using htmunit without proxy.

All the requests are the same between Fiddler and Charlesproxy, but a new page loads when I use Fiddler. I want this page to load without using Fiddler as a proxy, but I'm trying to figure out what it causing the page to load when Fiddler is used as a proxy. Does Fiddler have any options that modifies requests/responses automatically?

Comment: `a new page loads when I use Fiddler` => What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler will modify the request or response if and only if you tell instruct it to do so, using FiddlerScript, and extension, or features like the Filters tab.

For anyone to help you, you'll need to elaborate on what *different results* you're experiencing. What does "a new page loads" mean exactly?